# How to connect sqllite to c# application

Tags: c#

Hello I am a new in C# and I have this problem. How can I connect my sqllite database in C#?
I created class named Connection.cs I know I have to get connectionString but I don´t know how to set up it. In my project I have alredy database test.db in main project folder (I can see it in my project in VS)

Can you show me how to make this connection working (some example class or something)? My idea is that I am doing MVP design model so I have to use this connection in my models.

I would show you my code but there is not so much to show. I saw some videos how to connect this but thy always need nugget package to make connection working. Is this only way or is there other option to do it?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your question. This is too broad. What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env, data types & expected result, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Personally, I use [SQLite ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) that allows to use strongly typed DataSets and all RAD Designers of Visual Studio. This is the one I have found that works the best being open source (and multi-platform). You can learn ADO.NET with the unique and awesome book [Beginning C # 2005 Databases](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Beginning+C%23+2005+Databases-p-9780470044063) for example. There are several free and commercial [SQLite ADO.NET](https://system.data.sqlite.org) providers available around the world.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to following article to get started with using SQLite in C# application.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application

Recommended practice is to put your database file in App_Data folder of the application. Regarding database connectionstrings refer to following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj653752(v=vs.110)

Following is a link to video series on YouTube that may be complete guide to what you are looking for.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHw4bBLM8Vk&list=PLT3ocvD4YC8iHBHQxFq13r-8rQyQxoJOx&index=1